# Monaco Editor Console error: Unexpected Usage at EditorSimpleWorker.loadForeignModule

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I am getting Unexpected Usage error Console error when using Monaco Editor inside Electron App. The same code works in Website mode but not in Bundled Electorn app.

[image: Console error Unexpected usage in Monaco Editor]

As mentioned in [comment at](https://github.com/jaywcjlove/react-monacoeditor/issues/1#issuecomment-418691675) it may be due to Electron bundle uses file:/// as URI scheme and webworker doesn't work. I have tried solutions from multiple threads [1](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2122#issuecomment-691893933), [2](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin/issues/32) but none worked for me. I have also tried to add entry points in webpack for editor.worker, json/typescript workers.

Is there a workaround to get Monaco Webworker issue fixed fro Electron bundled app?

Comment: We have moved to https://codemirror.net/ due to this reason. As that provides most of functionality required with custom plugins/scripts.